# How to re-run one line of a PowerShell cmdlet if it fails

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script which is supposed to send emails automatically, but sometimes the email won't send out due to a network issue.

Here is how I'm sending email:

```
$smtp_notification.Send($mail_notification)
```

Here are the error logs:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At line:1 char:24
+ $smtp_notification.Send <<<< ($mail_notification)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Is there anyway to re-run the sending line when I met this failure? Can anyone give me some suggestions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a loop with a try block in it, very simplistically:

```
$worked = $false
while (-not $worked) {
  try {
    #Perform command to retry, passing -ErrorAction Stop

    $worked = $true  # An exception will skip this
  } catch {
    # Should check to retry: error record is in $_
  }
}
```